# What does Box::new actually do in this code snippet in Rust?

Tags: rust

Why does it use `Box::new` to place a `BufReader` object into a `Box`?

Why doesn't just simply use the return value of `BufReader::new`?

```
let mut buf: Box<dyn BufRead> = Box::new(BufReader::new(fs::File::open("file.txt")?));
```

Comment: Basically it casts the value to a generic type rather than a concrete type. Generic types can't be used directly since their size depends on what the actual underlying concrete type is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your misunderstanding could come from two parts in this snippet: the use of a trait object, and the use of a `Box`.

Notice that the type declared for the variable `buf` (ie. `Box<dyn BufRead>`) does *not* match the type of the value it is assigned to (ie. `Box<BufReader<_>>`). That is, Rust performs an "implicit" cast for you. The exact cast that is performed is `BufReader<_>` is casted to a `dyn BufRead`, which is possible because `BufReader<_>: BufRead`.

If you don't know that `dyn Trait` means, given a trait `Trait`, please read about [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html). One peculiarity of trait objects is that they are never `Sized`, ie. the compiler can never know their size in advance, simply because a type with *any* size could be created, implement a given trait, and thus be a possible concrete type for a trait object. For this reason, you need to allocate it on the heap, which is basically what `Box` does.

A `Box` is a, basically, an owned pointer, that is, it's a pointer to data allocated on the heap, but with the peculiarity that whomever owns the box also owns its content (which is not the case, for instance, of `&T`). This also means that instantiating a new `Box` takes care of allocating directly on the heap. If you want more details about memory allocation on the heap vs on the stack in Rust, I would recommend [reading about it](https://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/first-edition/the-stack-and-the-heap.html).

Comment: I did some other research, and it seems nothing wrong if I simply use `let mut buf: BufReader<File> = BufReader::new(fs::File::open("file.txt").unwrap());`, as you mentioned above, because a trait object is never sized, so `Box` is used. Is that because a trait object size is unpredictable, and allocating an unpredictable size object on stack is not safe, so use `Box` to guarantee the safety, right?

Comment: @LouisWong this is not a safety concern, but a feasibility concern. When you allocate an object on the stack, you must know its size at compile time (this is not specific to Rust, but rather to how the stack works).

Comment: Thank you kindly @BlackBeans for the answers above.